# Aumentar tamaño de una partición de un disco, con partición de otro disco

Tags: windows

Tengo actualmente en mi Servidor de datos Windows Server 2012 un serio problema.

Actualmente mi servidor cuenta con 2 discos mecánicos, uno de 120Gb (de arranque) y uno de 500 Gb (de datos), el cual brinda el servicio de almacenamiento de datos, y acceden varios usuarios desde diferentes equipos, pero el problema que tengo es que el disco de datos ya esta colapsando, puesto que ya no dispone de más espacio de almacenamiento, ante lo cual necesito encontrar alguna forma de que aumentar el tamaño (lógico) del disco, aumentando otro disco físico de tal forma que no se alteren las rutas de acceso al disco, solo aumente el tamaño como tal. De antemano indico que no he encontrado la forma de hacer esto en todos los sitios que he buscado, solo se puede aumentar cuando el espacio es del mismo disco físico, mas no cuando el espacio es de otro disco diferente.

Comment: ¿Y si compras un disco más grande y lo dejas copiando todo de un lado a otro en la noche, por ejemplo, luego sacas el antiguo y le asignas al nuevo la misma letra de unidad que tenía? Tendrás que volver a crear los recursos compartidos. Existe forma de unir 2 o más discos, [Windows 2012 spanned volume](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+2012+spanned+volume), sin embargo la configuración inicial es destructiva con la data. Así que parece que en cualquier caso tocará copiar la información.

Comment: Saludos @aeportugal

Primero agradecerte por haberte tomado el tiempo de leer mi consulta y brindar tu oportuna sugerencia.
Voy a tener muy en cuenta tu sugerencia, tanto al momento de hacer el respaldo y usar "Windows 2012 spanned", y bueno la verdad que he intentado y buecado mucho la forma de expandir una particion de un disco, con disco, u otra particion pero de otro disco mediante algun software, pero como indique al inicio, al parecer realizar esta opcion es imposible.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de investigar y hacer algunas pruebas con un *WINSERVER 2012* de testeo que monté, debo indicar que ya he logrado dar con la solución. El problema propuesto logra solventarse convirtiendo los discos que son de tipo básico a dinámicos. Una vez que los discos son dinámicos, ya se dispone de varias opciones que se pueden realizar en los discos, tipos distribuidos, espejos, extendido y más. Con esta característica en los discos ya es posible realizar la configuración inicialmente propuesta y motivo de mi consulta.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Ten presente además que [es.so] es un sitio (no un foro) de preguntas acerca de _programación_. Tu pregunta justamente cae en el limbo de preguntas permitidas aquí, ya que sabemos que no existe otro sitio de SE en español que se adecue a la temática de ella.